# Determine coordinates of rotated rectangle

Tags: javascript, algorithm, image-processing

I'm creating an utility application that should detect and report the coordinates of the corners of a transparent rectangle (alpha=0) within an image.

So far, I've set up a system with Javascript + Canvas that displays the image and starts a floodfill-like operation when I click inside the transparent rectangle in the image. It correctly determines the bounding box of the floodfill operation and as such can provide me the correct coordinates.

Here's my implementation so-far: http://www.scriptorama.nl/image/ (works in recent Firefox / Safari ).

However, the bounding box approach breaks down then the transparent rectangle is rotated (CW or CCW) as the resulting bounding box no longer properly represents the proper width and height. I've tried to come up with a few alternatives to detect to corners, but have not been able to think up a proper solution.

So, does anyone have any suggestions on how I might approach this so I can properly detect the coordinates of 4 corners of the rotated rectangle?

Comment: This isn't clear. Your sample seems to correctly identify the bounding box. Are you having trouble implementing the flood fill? Why does this require finding the corners? Flood-fills usually work by finding edge pixels without concern for geometrical entities.

Comment: Indeed, the bounding-box works fine and it is detected by applying a floodfill algorithm. 

However, I need the exact coordinates of the corners of the rectangle (-not- the bounding box) and I'm not sure how to approach that problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do this with a simple extension to your existing solution: walk along each of the 4 edges of the bounding box, looking for transparent pixels:

- In the non-rotated case, all the pixels along each edge of the box will be transparent.
- In the rotated case, there must be one corner touching each edge of the box.  This will be at the transparent pixel furthest away from the middle of the edge (there may be more than one due to aliasing, e.g. if the rectangle is only very slightly rotated).

Comment: That works great, Matthew. I've almost got it working perfectly, just have to deal with inaccuracies due to antialiasing, as you predicted. Thanks!